# Let Visual Studio (2015) link headers and libraries for other computers

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I need a way to setup Visual Studio, in this case VS2015, to find some header files and libraries directly on a different computer. Because as it is now, I need to send a project to another person and the linking I have done on my computer won't be supported on that person's, as the include path is different. Is there a way to do this if I include a subfolder in the project with all the headers and libraries needed - something like "Include dir"?

**Note:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776042/how-to-handle-and-include-headers-and-libraries-for-building-a-visual-studio-201) thread, which seem to have a similar problem, but I couldn't get a straight answer out of it.

Comment: What you're probably after is a standalone or self-contained binary

Comment: This sounds like the wrong problem to solve.  Why isn't the other persons code in some sort of source control program so that you can just grab it?  If you have multiple people working on a project you pretty much *need* source control, it'll make things so much easier long term.